# C# Как получить время подписания из PKCS7 подписи с помощью BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

есть система, в которую я импортирую подписи(Система закрытая). В нашем формате PKCS7 хранятся несколько подписующих, то есть подписывает сначала один человек, потом второй, потом третий. С помощью BouncyCastle я разделяю эти подписи и импортирую в систему. Проблема заключается в следующем, после того, подписал последний человек, как импортировать именно его подпись, а не случайную из массива? Я пробовал доставать с помощью Last(), и у меня выходил первый подписующий, но если воспользоваться First(), то выходит кто-то рандомный из всего масива.
Код разъединения подписей:

```
 var result = new List<byte[]>();

  var signedData = SignedData.GetInstance(ContentInfo.GetInstance(Asn1Object.FromByteArray(signature)).Content);
  var digestAlgorithms = signedData.DigestAlgorithms != null ? new DerSet(signedData.DigestAlgorithms.OfType<Asn1Encodable>().Distinct().ToArray()) : null;
  var certificates = signedData.Certificates != null ? new DerSet(signedData.Certificates.OfType<Asn1Encodable>().Distinct().ToArray()) : null;
  var crls = signedData.CRLs != null ? new DerSet(signedData.CRLs.OfType<Asn1Encodable>().Distinct().ToArray()) : null;

  foreach(var signerInfo in signedData.SignerInfos.ToArray())
  {
    var newSignedData = new SignedData(digestAlgorithms, signedData.EncapContentInfo, certificates, crls, new DerSet(signerInfo));
    result.Add(new ContentInfo(CmsObjectIdentifiers.SignedData, newSignedData).GetDerEncoded());
  }

  return result;
```

Comment: Отсортируйте по дате подписания `OrderBy` и возьмите последнего. Либо если вам нужна подпись конкретной категории, то должен быть список валидных подписей, тогда задача сведется к перебору всех и проверке на наличие нужной.

Comment: Чтобы сортировать с помощью OrderBy, нужно ввести параметр даты, который нужно вытащить из подписи(с BouncyCastle работаю всего несколько недель). Вопрос как раз таки и заключается в том, как получить данный параметр.

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7360235/12888024) [Еще ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926977/12888024)

Comment: Вроде да, спасибо